# Return value outside the all loops

Tags: javascript

How to return my `serviceName` array outside the all loops?

Here is my code:

```
data.forEach(async (e) => {
  let serviceName = [];

  const orders = await this.getOrders(e.id);

  orders.forEach(async (a) => {
    serviceName.push(a.serviceName);
  });
});

return serviceName; //NOT WORK
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Move the declaration above `data.forEach(async e => {`. Although, if you're doing an asynchronous loop, you probably need `for..of` with `await` inside, or `Promise.all` depending on whether you need to do this sequentially or if it's OK to happen in parallel

Comment: can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`for..of loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to iterate over asynchronous functions and return the results.

```
(async () => {
    let serviceName = [];
    for (const item of data) {
        const orders = await this.getOrders(item.id);

        for (const order of orders) {
            serviceName.push(order.serviceName);
        }
    }
    
    return serviceName;
})();
```

For the parallel version -

Write a function that accepts an array of promises which won't fail fast because of [`Promise.all's`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) behavior, filter the resolved promises, and map the service names into the new array.

```
(async () => {
    const whenAll = (promises) => {
        const reflect = (promise) => {
            return promise.then((data) => ({
                status: 'Resolved',
                data
            }))
            .catch((err) => ({
                status: 'Rejected',
                error: err
            }));
        };

        return Promise.all(promises.map(reflect));
    };

    const promiseArr = data.map((item) => this.getOrders(item.id));
    const promiseResult = (await whenAll(promiseArr)).filter((res) => res.status === 'Resolved');
    const serviceName = promiseResult.map(({ data }} => data.serviceName);
    return serviceName;
})();
```

Comment: FYI: This will execute one item after the other

Comment: @MauriceNino the OP hasnt specified if he wants it in parallel

Comment: That's why I put a "FYI" there :) It's just a hint for anyone using it, not a problem with your code

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with async functions, I suggest you to use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`:

```
let = []; // declared outside the loop

const serviceNames = await Promise.all(
  data.map(async (e) => {
    const orders = await this.getOrders(e.id);

    return orders.map((a) => a.serviceName); // return the array of serviceName
  })
);

return serviceNames.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), []); // or use flatMap if you are running a newer JS version
```